# Grant Database Access for Reporting Services: A connection to the computer cannot be established

Tags: reporting-services

On a single Windows 2008 Server I'm running SharePoint 2007 Enterprise (SP2, December 2009 CU) and SQL Server 2005 (SP3, CU 7). Authentication is NTLM. I've been trying to get SharePoint Reporting Services integration to work without success.

The Reporting Services configuration tool has all ticks. It is possible to browse to the ReportServer IIS directory and see a list of SharePoint sites. The Reporting Services URL has been set within Central Administration.

When I fill in the "Grant Database Access" form with a user account and click OK, the following message displays: 'A connection to the computer cannot be established'. There is no error logged to the ULS logs or the Reporting Services logs about this.

I've tried:

- a complete uninstall and reinstall both SQL Server and SharePoint (as it is impossible to only uninstall the Reporting Services component with SQL Server 2005)
- used the same service account for all SQL services and the same for all SharePoint services
- given all service accounts domain administrator and local administrator permissions
- enabled Named Pipes and TCP/IP networking within SQL Server
- followed [Troubleshooting Server and Database Connection Problems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156468%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

... all to no success! Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked was to [turn off UAC as mentioned in this forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointbi/thread/938b5009-45de-48d3-a36e-c21ddf339c8f).

As that poster mentions, it would be great to know how to do this without turning off UAC.

Another resource: [Troubleshooting Integration with SQL Server 2005 and Microsoft SharePoint Technologies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb969101%28SQL.90%29.aspx).